# Windows Phone 8.1 Salvando Estado do ToggleSwitch

Tags: c#, windows-phone, xaml

**Tenho um codigo onde preciso salvar o estado do ToggleSwitch.
Para que ao iniciar a pagina o mesmo fique com a propriedade Ison ativa ou inativa, de acordo como o usuário havia selecionado.**

***Porém ao iniciar esta sempre atribuindo '1' que representa estar ativo.***

Para salvar o estado do elemento tenho usado ''Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;'' que é o substituto do IsolatedStorageSettings para WP8.1.

Segue o Cod. Abaixo:

```
  using Windows.Storage;

  namespace TESTE
 {

public sealed partial class opcoes : Page
{
   public ApplicationDataContainer settings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
       
    public opcoes()
    {
        statusToggles();
        this.InitializeComponent();          
        this.navigationHelper = new NavigationHelper(this);
        this.navigationHelper.LoadState += this.NavigationHelper_LoadState;
        this.navigationHelper.SaveState += this.NavigationHelper_SaveState;

     }
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        statusToggles();
    }       
   
    // Evento disparado pelo ToggledSwitch
    private void bgaleatorio_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ToggleSwitch toggleSwitch = sender as ToggleSwitch;
        bgpar(toggleSwitch);
        
    }
    // statusToggles() -> Verifica se  bgaleatorio for 1 ou 0 o Toggle será ativo ou inativo respectivamente
    private void statusToggles()
    {
        Object tempsetings = settings.Values["bgaleatorio"];
        if (tempsetings == "1") { bgaleatorio.IsOn = true; }
        if (tempsetings == "0") { bgaleatorio.IsOn = false; }

    }
    // bgpar -> Recebe um ToggleSwitch como parametro e Grava em settings.Values["bgaleatorio"] os valores 0 ou 1  de acordo com o Statatus do ToggleSwitch
    private void bgpar(ToggleSwitch toggleSwitch)
    {           
        if (toggleSwitch.IsOn == true)
        {
            settings.Values["bgaleatorio"] = "1";
        }

        else if (toggleSwitch.IsOn == false)
        {
            settings.Values["bgaleatorio"] = "0";
        }

    }       
    
}     
}
```

Codigo Xaml:

```
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="bgaleatorio" Header="Background Aleatório" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,123,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="287" IsOn="True" FontSize="11" Grid.RowSpan="2" Toggled="bgaleatorio_Toggled" />
```

Comment: Coloca um Breakpoint em statusToggles(), na linha após Object tempsettings... e inspeciona o valor que veio na variável.

Comment: Fiz isso, apos rodar o app por padrão a propriedade ISon vem true. Alterei para false  settings.Values["bgaleatorio"] recebeu 0.
Sai da pagina, ao retornar ele chama o statusToggles.O mesmo tras o valor 0 do ["bgaleatorio"] porém  bgaleatorio.IsOn vem null e ele não aplica true ou false se ["bgaleatorio"] for 1 ou 0 respectivamente.

Comment: Codigo Xaml:
<ToggleSwitch x:Name="bgaleatorio" Header="Background Aleatório" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="68,123,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="287" IsOn="True" FontSize="11" Grid.RowSpan="2" Toggled="bgaleatorio_Toggled"/>

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297/quando-se-deve-colocar-o-nome-da-linguagem-no-t%c3%adtulo/1911#1911 E quando for adicionar informações, prefira [edit] a pergunta. É muito difícil ler certas informações em comentários, além de fragmentar a informação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui!

Criei o Toggle em codigo behind, precisava estanciá-lo antes de tentar atribui alguma propriedade.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHNullReference);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-WindowsPhoneApp,Version%3Dv8.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

Answer (score -1):

O melhor seria passar o `statusToggles();` para o `Loaded` da página.